# Is AWS S3 a reliable way for hosting huge files for download over HTTP/HTTPS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Our project has a directory of huge files spanning from 900MB to 2GB of file sizes.

The objective is to allow end-users to download huge files using typical web browsers.

Can AWS S3 as a file server be good option for this kind of application?

Comment: to the one who downvoted this question, please state the reason just so we can improve the details of the question

Comment: When you ask about downloading huge files, are you looking for chunked file contents when downloaded and then reassembled?

Comment: @SunilSinghal Yes, that is the objective. To allow chunked downloads for huge files.

Answer (score 1):

In short yes

The maximum object size is 5 terabytes

There are various options for optimising the storage type to reduce the cost

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: Yes. More info: Amazon S3 Standard offers high durability, availability, and performance object storage for frequently accessed data. Because it delivers low latency and high throughput, Standard is perfect for a wide variety of use cases including cloud applications, dynamic websites, content distribution, mobile and gaming applications, and big data analytics. Lifecycle management offers configurable policies to automatically migrate objects to the most appropriate storage class.

Key Features:
Low latency and high throughput performance,
Designed for durability of 99.999999999% of objects,
Designed for 99.99% availability over a given year,
Backed with the Amazon S3 Service Level Agreement for availability.
Supports SSL encryption of data in transit and at rest and
Lifecycle management for automatic migration of objects.

Comment: Please provide source when quoting. Also, I don't think this addresses the OP's questions.